# How to edit View in Activity from DatePickerFragment?

Tags: android

I have some issue with DatePickerFragment. I can't get how to edit my textView in activity from DatePickerFragment (onDateSet method). One thing that works is to make textview static, but in that case i get a warning: Do not place android context classes into static fields.

Can I ignore that warning or what other way to update my view?

My code looks like this:

```
public class Ad1StatsFilterActivity extends BaseActivity {
private static final String TAG = "Ad1StatsFilterActivity";
static TextView dateFrom;
TextView dateTo;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForTextView;
static String dateFromPicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad1_stats_filter);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    activateToolbar(true);

    dateFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ad1_filter_period_from);
    dateTo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ad1_filter_period_to);

    dateFormatForTextView = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM YYYY", Locale.getDefault());
    final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(new Date());

    final String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

    Spinner dateSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ad1_filter_date_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.ad1_date_filter, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    dateSpinner.setSelection(0);
    //Spinner
    dateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    dateFrom.setText(dateFormatForTextView.format(new Date()));
                    dateTo.setText(dateFormatForTextView.format(new Date()));
                    break;

                case 2:
                    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected: dateFromPiker = " + dateFromPicker);
                    if (dateFromPicker != null) dateFrom.setText(dateFromPicker);
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


}


public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private static final String TAG = "DatePickerFragment";


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        dateFromPicker = dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime());
        dateFrom.setText(dateFromPicker);


    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }


}
```

}

I also need two different Dates (Date from and date to). I found a solution how to do this, but now its deprecated. What is the best way to get two different DatePicker dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

> but in that case i get a warning: Do not place android context classes
>   into static fields.
>
> Can I ignore that warning or what other way to update my view?

Never ever try to do that. It cause memory leak and prevent your activity from being garbage collected.

Try removing static modifier from your `DatePickerFragment`:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
```

By doing this you do not need to have static references to your textviews.

> I also need two different Dates (Date from and date to)

This is something that you should handle. For example you can use a Boolean identifier to indicate whether the chosen date is `From Date` or `To Date`

Comment: I removed static modifier as you said, but i now i got warning: This fragment inner class should be static. (Project compiles without errors)

Answer (score 0):

First of all no need to make DatePickerFragment class as static and thus the text view. Clean solution to update text view from DatePickerFragment would be.

1. Declare an interface something like

   `interface DateChangedListner{
        onDatePicked(String date);
     }`
2. Implement the interface in your activity and pass the interface impl object to DatePickFragment when creating it from activity.
3. Invoke the interface impl object whenever user select the date or so from DatePickerFragment
4. Implementation of interface will contain updating the text view inside activity itself.

Comment: How should i pass the interface impl object to DatePickFragment? Pass it to constructor?

Comment: But what about "Avoid non-default constructors in fragments"?